# What is the date format String for 29 Sep, 30 Sep, 02 Oct etc

Tags: android

I tried the following code for this.

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM");
dateFormatter.parse("13 Jan");
```

but it raising parse exception invalid date.

Comment: I tried this. It generate exception "Unparseable date"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the `dd MMM` format. So you need to use it as

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
```

---

Read [***Date and Time Patterns***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for more details.

---

*There might another issue. For your current input, format `"d MMM"` will also work.*

Answer (score 0):

Try it as:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM"); // dd for date, MMM for Month
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formatter.format(calendar.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope it helps.